# In Magento1.9x how do I get product image from an external URL

Tags: magento-1.9

I am Magento newbie and working on a new Project.  Our products supplier has a product image CDN and they authorized us to export the images so that we can upload to our Magento product image files. But these are hundred of images and the export/upload process is quite time consuming.

Is there a way to just show/load the image from a link to the CDN URL so that we can skip the export/upload process?

ivanjaen

Answer (score 2):

There is no such process to upload images in magento. You can import all the images at a time. This can be done through CSV import. But we cant import through a CDN url. For importing images through CSV, Follow the steps.

1. First you have to upload alll the images you want to import in the media/import/yourimagesfolder/
2. The in the CSV columns for image, thumbnail and small_image your image path should look like this

/yourimagefolder/imagename.jpg

3. At last you have to import the CSV.

Answer (score 1):

I just finished building my first site in Magento and faced the same issue. We did not find a solution that matched your problem. In the end we found [MaxCDN](http://www.maxcdn.com/) to be the simplest solution for us. However we still had to upload all of our 9,000 plus images. I look forward to the rest of your replies for additional knowledge.

Fitz

Answer (score 0):

Sadly there is no such way to import images from CDN. But you can use Magmi's image importer function to make your life a lot easier...